# Get Android device/emulator root directory

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am developing an Android application using Eclipse/Ubuntu. As usual, I am doing the first shot on an AVD emulator. I would like to put in place a unique folder structure that I can use on both the current emulator and on the final physical device (the SD memory card).
What would be the Android environment variable to pick up the root directory by program (Java of course) for both type of virtual and physical devices, so that I can have my starting reference?
Thanks
PS: I have the DDMS File Explorer open, in case the answer refers to the structure there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html to get the "same" directory with `getExternalStorageDirectory()` method

Comment: and [Context#getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) to get to your app's "home directory" where only your app can read / write files per default.

Comment: @both: thanks for the right answers. I understand that the best programming approach - as access rights and system management (in case of uninstalling the application) - is to use what is returned by Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.xx), which, in my case is /mnt/sdcard/

Answer (score 2):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You need user permission if you want to write in storage

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

This will create instance of your root directory

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is **deprecated** and Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, should be used instead.

> This method was deprecated in API level 29.
>   To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps. Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to alternatives such as Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()