# Java: FileNotFoundException when file exists

Tags: java, android, xml, file, load

I've been extensively researching this problem for the past two hours. I have the following code:

```
File fXmlFile = new File("falstad/skill.xml");
System.out.println(fXmlFile);
if (!fXmlFile.exists()) {
    Log.v("filereader", "Doesn't exist");
}

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

"falstad" is the package that holds both skill.xml and the Java file that is trying to load skill.xml. However, "Doesn't exist" is logged, indicating that fXmlFile does not exist, and the line

```
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
```

throws the error. I've tried all sorts of path combinations, ranging from starting with the C drive to just loading "skill.xml". But no matter what I put it won't load the file. I'm working on an Android app for Android 4.4.2. Any advice on why the file isn't loading?

Comment: What is the current working directory when this code is called? You can print it with `System.out.println( System.getProperty("user.dir"))`. Relative paths are relative to this directory.

Comment: "user.dir" printed a slash. What does that mean?

Comment: Sounds like your working directory is the root directory. If you want to use a relative path, you could start the application with a descendant of '/' as the working directory, and specify a path relative to that descendant. An alternative is to use an absolute path - one that starts with '/'.

Comment: So what I tried was
    File fXmlFile = new File("/ProjectName", "/src/falstad/skill.xml");
but I got nothing from that either. Am I wrong in assuming the root directory is the directory of all projects? I'm working in Eclipse. Or how would I go about changing the working directory of the application?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027830/get-android-device-emulator-root-directory .

Comment: If falstad is a package, should not you load a resource from classpath rather then file from file system?