# How can I find the root directories in android?

Tags: android, file, path

In windows, I display all the root directories of the system using the below code

```
import java.io.*; 



public class GFG { 



public static void main(String args[]) 

{ 

    // roots of the path name 

    File root[] = File.listRoots(); 



    // check if the root is null or not 

    if (root != null) { 

        System.out.print("Roots are: "); 



        // display the roots of the path name 

        for (int i = 0; i < root.length; i++) { 

            System.out.print(root[i].getPath() + " "); 

        } 

    } 

    else

        System.out.println("There are no roots"); 

} 
}
```

**output:**

```
Roots are: C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\ G:\
```

But , How can I display in android ?

I want to display  directories  like internal storage path , sdcard storage path or if I connect pendrive via usb display pendrive stroge path .

I want to get the paths of all root  directories like sdcard path , internal storage path and usb pendrive path.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Those are not directories but partitions. And "/" is root for all paths on Android.

Comment: follow this way and read doc.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12027918/12709358

Comment: Can you give more information?